# Grails 3.2.11 war file is more than 70Mb

Tags: grails, war

I used command grails war. The war file created is 75Mb. What might be the reason and how can I create war with small size. 
The same project folder is 14Mb.

Comment: Check what library files have been included in the lib directories. You may have unnecessary dependencies.

Comment: I found huge number of libraries in project structure > Libraries. Are there ways to remove unused libraries? I am new to Grails.

Comment: check the `build.gradle` file, dependencies are added here too. As the directory is on 14mb (I'm assuming this size includes the lib folders, if not delete the unwanted jars from the lib folders )

Comment: You should be able to open the war file as if it were a zip (rename to .zip and open with whatever client you're use to). Might give you some insight as to what's causing the large size.

Comment: yes I found the libraries folder resulting high memory usage

Answer (score 1):

When we create grails project it adds many dependencies to our project which download jar files and add to our project.

There are many unnecessary dependencies are added which you remove as per your requirement.

So Go to build.gradle file in your project

dependencies {

testCompile "org.grails:grails-web-testing-support"

//testCompile "org.grails.plugins:geb"

...

}

Simply you can remove dependency or comment using //

[image]

Once removed/commented dependencies, please refresh gradle project
then run command `grails clean`

now create war file with `war` command

Hope it helps you